# Loop through array of object where it's elements contains array of elements that can be repeated, then return match

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, find

I'm having troubles with looping. My JSON is in the link at the end.

//user can choose any programming language and platform he wants (or none), and it'll be written for example in variables *uProgLang*  and *uPlatform* :

```
let uProgLang = "java";
let uPlatform = "Google Dialogflow";

let coupon = await Coupon.find({ 'programming_language': [uProgLang], 'chatbot_platform': [uPlatform ] }).map(function(item){
            if(programming_language.item == uProgLang || chatbot_platform.item == uPlatform )
                return coupon.link;
        });
if (coupon !== null ) {
      if(coupon.programming_language && coupon.chatbot_platform)
            responseText = `${uProgLang} for ${uPlatform} is available on: ${coupon.link}`;
      else if(coupon.programming_language)  
            responseText = `${uProgLang} is available on: ${coupon.link}`;
      else if(coupon.chatbot_platform)  
            responseText = `${uPlatform} is available on: ${coupon.link}`;
}else 
      responseText = `Here is link to all...`;
```

[my JSON document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HysF9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, so I want to contribute to community (by the way, this was my first question, and now this is my first answer on stackoverflow yuuhuuu! ..feeling proud )

```js
//-------------------------- JSON_beginning --------------------------
const books = [
    {
        _id: { oid: "1" },
        programming_language: ["nodejs"],
        chatbot_platform: ["Google Dialogflow"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/1"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "2" },
        programming_language: ["python"],
        chatbot_platform: ["NLP"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/2"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "3" },
        programming_language: ["c#"],
        chatbot_platform: ["Microsoft Bot Framework"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/3"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "4" },
        programming_language: ["python", "java"],
        chatbot_platform: ["NLP", "Rasa", "Google Dialogflow", "Microsoft Bot Framework"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/4"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "5" },
        programming_language: ["ruby"],
        chatbot_platform: [""],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/5"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "6" },
        programming_language: ["typescript"],
        chatbot_platform: ["Microsoft Bot Framework"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/6"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "7" },
        programming_language: ["python"],
        chatbot_platform: ["NLP"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/7"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "8" },
        programming_language: ["java", "nodejs"],
        chatbot_platform: ["Twilio", "Alexa Skills", "Google Dialogflow", "Microsoft Bot Framework", "Chatfuel"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/8"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "9" },
        programming_language: [""],
        chatbot_platform: ["Google Dialogflow"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/9"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "10" },
        programming_language: ["nodejs"],
        chatbot_platform: ["Amazon Lex"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/10"
    },
    {
        _id: { oid: "11" },
        programming_language: ["c#"],
        chatbot_platform: ["Microsoft Bot Framework"],
        link: "https://www.amazon.com/111"
    }
]
//-------------------------- JSON_end --------------------------


// Inside those 2 variables put any programming language and/or any platform contained in JSON object, or none
let uProgLang = "";
let uPlatform = "";


console.log(` \n ******************************************************************* `);
console.log(' ************************** beginning ****************************** ');
console.log(' ******************************************************************* ');

/* Just add this before for searching through database
const books = await Coupon.find({
  $or: [{ programming_language: uProgLang }, { chatbot_platform: uPlatform }],
}); */
// Only programming language selected
const arrayOfObjMatchedProgLang = books.filter(function (k) {
  if(uProgLang !=="")
    return k.programming_language.includes(uProgLang);
}).map(function (l) { return l.link });
console.log(arrayOfObjMatchedProgLang); 

console.log(' ------------------------------------------------------------------- ');


// Only platform selected
const arrayOfObjMatchedPlatform = books.filter(function (k) {
  if(uPlatform !=="")
    return k.chatbot_platform.includes(uPlatform);
}).map(function (l) { return l.link });
console.log(arrayOfObjMatchedPlatform);

console.log(' ------------------------------------------------------------------- ');

// Both programming language & platform selected
let intersection = arrayOfObjMatchedProgLang.filter(x => arrayOfObjMatchedPlatform.includes(x));
console.log(intersection);



console.log(` \n ******************** Printing text with links *********************\n `);
// ***** Printing text with links *****
let responseText;

// Both selected
if (uProgLang && uPlatform)
  responseText = `Books for ${uProgLang} programming language with ${uPlatform} chatbot platform is available on:\n` +intersection.join("\n");
// Only programming language
else if (uProgLang)
  responseText = `Books for ${uProgLang} programming language is available on:\n` +arrayOfObjMatchedProgLang.join("\n");
// Only platform
else if (uPlatform)
  responseText = `Books for ${uPlatform} chatbot platform is available on:\n` +arrayOfObjMatchedPlatform.join("\n");
// Neither one selected  
else
  responseText = `Here is some random link :) \n`+
`https://ctl.s6img.com/society6/img/5gOI6Pvx09XYIfUVhBXh9qTr1oo/w_700/prints/~artwork/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/misc/fa0dafda81cb466ca8b06922f36e7690/~~/cute-penguins-a-cute-illustrated-penguin-in-blue-and-white-t-shirt-design-hearts-cool-penguin-dab-prints.jpg`;
console.log(responseText);



console.log(` \n ******************************************************************* `);
console.log(' **************** end - thx for helping people ********************* ');
console.log(' ******************************************************************* ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```js
const coupons = await Coupon.find({
  $or: [{ programming_language: uProgLang }, { chatbot_platform: uPlatform }],
});

const couponsBoth = coupons.filter(
  (c) =>
    c.programming_language.includes(uProgLang) &&
    c.chatbot_platform.includes(uPlatform)
);
const couponsOnlyProgLang = coupons.filter(
  (c) =>
    c.programming_language.includes(uProgLang) &&
    !c.chatbot_platform.includes(uPlatform)
);
const couponsOnlyPlatform = coupons.filter(
  (c) =>
    !c.programming_language.includes(uProgLang) &&
    c.chatbot_platform.includes(uPlatform)
);

let responseText = "";

// Both
responseText += `${uProgLang} for ${uPlatform} is available on these links: \n${couponsBoth
  .map((c) => c.link)
  .join("\n")}\n`;
// Only Language
responseText += `${uProgLang} is available on these links: \n${couponsOnlyProgLang
  .map((c) => c.link)
  .join("\n")}\n`;
// Only platform
responseText += `${uPlatform} is available on these links: \n${couponsOnlyPlatform
  .map((c) => c.link)
  .join("\n")}\n`;
```

You should be able to tweak the response to fit what you have in mind.

Comment: First, thanks for ultra fast reply!!                                                                                      
We are close, but with this approach, it only gives me back first of that kind it finds, not when:                    // Both - not give me back all links that contains uProgLang and uPlatform, just the first it recognize                  
// Only Language - not give me back all links that contains just uProgLang. Instead I get only the first it recognize                    
// Only platform - not give me back links at all that contains just uPlatform. Just returns text

Comment: e.g. of exact response I get back from this code:
"Java for Google Dialogflow is available on these links: https://www.amazon.com/1 Java is available on these links: https://www.amazon.com/2 Google Dialogflow is available on these links:"